# How to add Linked list of objects to TableView using javafx/scene builder?

Tags: java, javafx, linked-list, tableview, scenebuilder

I'm developing a rather simple javafx application which has a few different scenes, my first scene is to add a Show object to a generic linked list and then in the second scene to add a performance of one of those shows to that object (e.g add matinee or evening performance to the show Annie)

I've created the first scene and can add Show objects to the linked list but I can't populate the tableview in the second scene with the created shows for the user to select and add a performance

This is what my add show controller looks like:

```
public class AddShowController {

    @FXML private TextField titleField;
    @FXML private TextField cirField,stlField, balField;
    @FXML private Slider runTimeSlider;
    @FXML private DatePicker startDatePicker, endDatePicker;
    TheLinkedList<Show> showList = new TheLinkedList<>();

    private static AddShowController instance;

    public AddShowController() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static AddShowController getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public void addShowButtonPushed (ActionEvent e){

        showList.addElement(new Show (titleField.getText(),
                                (int) runTimeSlider.getValue(),
                                startDatePicker.getValue().toString(),
                                endDatePicker.getValue().toString(),
                                cirField.getText(),
                                stlField.getText(),
                                balField.getText()));
}
```

As you can see I've tried creating an instance of the controller so i could access the linked list from the add performance controller but no joy.

This is the add performance controller:

```
public class AddPerfController {

    @FXML private ChoiceBox perfTimeChoiceBox;

    @FXML private TableView<Show> showTable;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Show, String> titleColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Show, String> runTimeColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Show, String> startDateColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Show, String> endDateColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Show, String> cirTicketPriceColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Show, String> stlTicketPriceColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Show, String> balTicketPriceColumn;

    private ObservableList<Show> showData = FXCollections.observableList(AddShowController.getInstance().showList);

    public void initialize() {
        perfTimeChoiceBox.getItems().addAll("Matinee","Evening");
        perfTimeChoiceBox.setValue("Matinee");

        titleColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("title"));
        runTimeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("runningTime"));
        startDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("startDate"));
        endDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("endDate"));
        cirTicketPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cirTicketPrice"));
        stlTicketPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stlTicketPrice"));
        balTicketPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("balTicketPrice"));

        showData.add(new Show("Annie", 100,"12/12/2019", "14/12/2019","10","15", "20"));
        showTable.setItems(showData);

    }
```

Comment: No idea, if `TheLinkedList` is properly implemented. However it's a bad choice as the backing list for an `ObservableList` used with `TableView`. Any performance you gain when inserting/removing elements is lost manifold during the updates of the table, since this does accesses by index...

Comment: I have to use a linked list for the assignment but theres no requirement to use a tableview, I just need to make the show objects selectable to the user in a separate scene, what would you suggest I use instead?

Comment: Depends on whether you need to use `TheLinkedList` in the model or not. In some cases simply copying it to a `ObservableList` using a different backing list may do the trick: `showTable.getItems().setAll(theList);` You may not see a difference btw, unless your list gets really big. Anyhow you need to create a [mcve]: Make sure we know which snippets are invoked in which order. Currently your code seems ok-ish, if you make several assumptions, e.g. only a single instance `AddShowController` (or subtypes) being created. (In general it's best to avoid the use of `static` to pass data)...

Answer (score 0):

We are not sure this is what your trying to do but have a look that the logic
We are using a Model View Controller because our data is in a Database
This is how we populate our Table named ctable not creative

```
    private void ReadFromChild() throws SQLException{

ObservableList<ChildModel> TableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    stmnt = conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Child WHERE cMonth ='"+strMONTH+"'AND cYear ='"+strYEAR+"'" );//works);
    while (rs.next()){// Add data to observableArrayList TableData to select a table ROW

    TableData.add(new ChildModel(rs.getString("CID"),rs.getString("cDisplayDate"),rs.getString("cTitle")));
    displayDATE = rs.getString("cDisplayDate");
    }
    PropertyValueFactory<ChildModel, String> IDCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("CID");
    colID.setCellValueFactory(IDCellValueFactory);
    PropertyValueFactory<ChildModel, String> DateCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("cDisplayDate");
    colDD.setCellValueFactory(DateCellValueFactory);
    PropertyValueFactory<ChildModel, String> TypeCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("cTitle");
    colTitle.setCellValueFactory(TypeCellValueFactory);

    Collections.sort(TableData, (p2, p1)-> p1.getCID().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getCID()));
    // Line of Code above Sorts Database Columns based on VARIABLE in ChildModel
    // Change p2,p1 to sort Ascending or Descending
    if(TableData.size() < 15) {// Format TableView to display Vertical ScrollBar
        ctable.setPrefWidth(746);// 19 is the off set
    }else {
        ctable.setPrefWidth(765);
    }   ctable.setItems(TableData);
    stmnt.close();  
}
```

OK when we click on a row in the table we go to another Controller here is the code for that

```
    private void toDetailView() throws IOException{
    stage = (Stage)childTVPane.getScene().getWindow();// pane you are ON
    detailviewPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("detailview.fxml"));// pane you are GOING TO
    Scene scene = new Scene(detailviewPane);// pane you are GOING TO
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("diary.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Diary Entry for "+displayDATE); 
    stage.show();
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.centerOnScreen(); 
}

private void showTableDataDetails(ChildModel info) throws IOException{
    if (info != null) {
       info =  (ChildModel) ctable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
       String str = info.getCID();
       strID = Integer.valueOf(str);
       toDetailView();
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    ctable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends ChildModel>
        observable,ChildModel oldValue, ChildModel newValue) -> {
        try {
            showTableDataDetails((ChildModel) newValue); // When a row of the table is Selected call
            // Proper Construction                   // showTableDataDetails method
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ParentTableViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: use java naming conventions, please (as you were asked more than once already - why don't you make you answers as readable as possible ;)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best solution but it solved my problem and just wanted to update this question.

I moved my LinkedList to the Main class and made it public static to access it from both controllers

```
public static TheLinkedList<Show> showList = new TheLinkedList<>();
```

In order to use the ObservableList I converted my LinkedList to an arrayList using the following method in my TheLinkedList class

```
    public  Show[] getShowList(){
        Show[] newShows = new Show[counter];

        sample.Node temp = Main.showList.getHead();
        for(int i = 0; i<counter;i++ ){
            newShows[i] = (Show)temp.getData();
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        return newShows;
    }
```

```
    public void initialize() {
    showData = FXCollections.observableArrayList((Main.showList.getShowList()));
     (column data) .......
    showTable.setItems(showData);

}
```

Comment: definitely the worst option - as fabian already noted: DO NOT USE global static fields to pass values between controllers, never-ever! The sooner you start with _not_ doing it the the better. For more appropriate options, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml